# How to log failed login attempts in Google Cloud Identity platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

We use Google Cloud Identity platform to support multi-tenant federated login. Depending on the tenant, we either user external identity providers or firebase authentication. For security compliance reasons, we would like to log failed login attempts. We looked into [activity logging](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/activity-logging), but failed login attempts seem to be not supported:

```
CreateAuthUri
GetRecaptchaParam
SendVerificationCode
SignInWithCustomToken
SignInWithEmailLink
SignInWithGameCenter
SignInWithIdp
SignInWithPassword
SignInWithPhoneNumber
SignUp
VerifyIosClient
```

We are now considering building a custom API to log these events, which seems like a lot of additional complexity for the use case. Would there be another way to log failed login attempts?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find documentation about Login audit logs where you can go to configure and view event names/types such as [failed login attempts](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/4580120?hl=en):

You can also view the reason of failed login attempt with [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/login#login_failure):

Comment: Answers should be self contained and answer the question. Links can be provided to complement an answer. Your post should be a comment to the question.

Comment: @LukeTerro it looks like this documentation applies to cloud identity/gsuite user management, and not really to our use case, where we use identity platform to allow our users (from external domains) to login via different routes.

Comment: I reviewed my new answer which provides where to find failed login attempts and how to configure/view them